# could not figure out how to get coroutines work correctly for inserting data into Room database

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I could not find the issue of not inserting the data into `Room Database` when app is launched first time, but when App is restarted data is inserted. Why not insertion is happening at first launch?

My code is:

```
@Dao
interface FooDAO {    
    @Insert
    suspend fun save(foo: Foo)            
}
```

and Database class is as simple:

```
@Database(entities = [Foo::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class FooDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    // get dao
    abstract fun getFooDao(): FooDAO

    companion object{

        @Volatile private var INSTANCE: FooDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): FooDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        FooDatabase::class.java,
                        "my_db.db"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(CALLBACK)
                        .build()
                }
            }

            return INSTANCE!!

        }

        private val CALLBACK = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                val fooDAO = INSTANCE!!.getFooDao()
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    fooDAO.save(Foo(1, "A"))
                    fooDAO.save(Foo(2, "B"))
                    fooDAO.save(Foo(3, "C"))
                    fooDAO.save(Foo(4, "D"))
                    fooDAO.save(Foo(5, "E"))                        
                }

            }
        }    

    }

}
```

with the code above records are not inserted at first launch of app but when it is restarted recordes are inserted, how can we fix this issue and make it insert records at first launch as well?

Comment: Your lazy init singleton is incorrectly implemented, it can create multiple instances. (Not claiming that this is the cause of your problem)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik any suggestion to make changes please.

Comment: You need to fully implement the double-checked lazy init idiom. Also, since `save` is a `suspend fun`, you don't have to wrap it into `withContext(IO)`. It does that on its own (just using a Room-specific thread pool).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik any code snippet please.

Comment: Actually the callbacks called when the database is accessed for the first time. It doesn't work like SQLite Helper, which creates database when app is run for the first time